# How to relatively link to a file

Tags: mediawiki

My max file upload size is 64MB on my host and I'd like to upload a larger file.  I see it as I have to upload the file via FTP and then link to it.  But it's important to be to use a relative link rather than permanent/direct link.  I'd like to put it in `/uploads/myfile.zip` but it ends up being a new wiki page rather than a file when I link to it from a wiki page.

Any suggestions on how I can get around that?

Comment: can't you just create a split archive and then extract on the host once all parts uploaded? eg '7z -v64m'

Comment: Or use some 3rd party file deposit area (DropBox share link, or something like yousendit?

Answer (score 0):

There are two extensions which should help you.

There is the [Extension:MultiUpload](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MultiUpload). If you upload files directly to the server using FTP or SCP or whatever, you have to import them into MediaWiki to make them work wiki-style, by using the maintenance/importImages.php file but it requires shell access.

There is also the [Extension:UploadLocal](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UploadLocal) which is good.